# Git not pushing new files to remote when doing force push to a different branch

Tags: git

I have two branches: `no-users` and `old-state`. Locally I was on `no-users`. I pulled from `old-state` and fixed the merge conflicts. Now I want to push to the `old-state` overwriting everything on this branch and transferring new files but force push (`git push -f origin old-state`) is somehow not pushing the files that were created in the `no-users` branch. `Git` is writing that the force push was run successfully, but the files are absent on remote.

Comment: Did you merge remote `origin/old-state` into local `no-users`? You should be merging `no-users` into `old-state` in order to push changes from `no-users` into `old-state`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you did

```
git push -f origin old-state
```

you pushed to the remote the commit `old-state` is poiting to, which hasn't changed since you merged `old-state` into `no-users`, not the contrary. That's why forcing didn't change a thing here. Your push was not *rejected*, it was just sending a ref the remote already has.

Only `no-users` has both parts of the tree at this point, so your best shot is to

```
git checkout old-state

# if you're not sure whether you're up-to-date on this branch,
# you might as well do it now before the merge
git pull

git merge no-users
```

and you'll be able to push without force :

```
git push origin old-state
```